# Can FlowLayoutPanel Be Used In a C Application Using CreateWindowEx()

Tags: c, windows, winforms, com, flowlayoutpanel

Can FlowLayoutPanel controls be used in a C application where the window was created using CreateWindowEx(), using the Windows Application Programming Interface (API) and Component Object Model (COM)? Is there a way to manipulate the Z-order of controls? Is there an equivalent to QGridLayout? If so, how do I access the controls, if not, is there any other way to do Flow Control in an application using C?

I have a Window, with a Tool Bar, a Status Bar and a List View, where the last two are created with CreateWindowEx(), that I am trying to lay out. So I am looking to find a way to lay out my Controls in such a way that my Controls can not overlay over each other, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not clear whether you have a C application (so you call `CreateWindow()` etc.) or you have a WinForms application (C# app, you create a new Form). Which is it? In any case, you can call `SetWindowPos()` with `HWND_TOP` or `HWND_BOTTOM` and `SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE` (in WinForms, you just call `BringToFront()` and `SendToBack()`)

Comment: It's a C application that uses CreateWindowEx() to create windows and controls, maybe the title confuses things. I've updated the question to make things more clear.

Comment: If you want to replicate in C a FlowLayoutPanel (not a Win32 control), you create a child window with `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT`, then create the logic that determines the layout of all parented child windows.  In WinForms, it's a dedicated class, derived from LayoutEngine , [FlowLayout](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Layout/FlowLayout) -- Good luck with that. FlowLayoutPanel is `ComVisible`, but... probably better create a Form in C# or PowerShell

Comment: I'm a bit of a sadist, so I'll have a look into "_create a child window with WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, then create the logic that determines the layout of all parented child windows_", and thank you...